# How to take a stringbuilder and convert it to a streamReader?

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

How to take a stringbuilder and convert it to a stream?

SO my stringbuilder has to be converted into a :

```
StreamReader stream = ????
```

**Update**

I tried using a stringreader like:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(sr);
```

but that doesn't work?

Answer (score 9):

Use ToString to convert the StringBuilder into a String, and use a StringReader to wrap the String as a Stream.

Comment: but a StreamReader doesn't take a StringReader?

Comment: If you have any control over it, have the function accept a TextReader (instead of StreamReader), which is the base class for both.  Otherwise, you may have to use the code Qua posted.

Answer (score 7):

If using a `StreamReader` is a requirement then convert the string to a memory stream and then create a new StreamReader using that object:

```
StreamReader reader= new StreamReader(
                new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString())));
```

Comment: This will result in two unnecessary allocations and copies of the data being made in memory (one by `sb.ToString()` another by `GetBytes()`). A better approach would be to subclass `TextReader` and implement it by reading directly from the `StringBuilder` instance.